# Upload multiple images to server with progress bar in a table

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, image-uploading

I want to upload multiple images to server.and want to show the progress as well for that i need to show all images with progress bar in table.

please suggest me what is the best way and if any sample code available will help much

Comment: hi you need to create a network queue object and set its download progress delegate to your progress bar and for every image use asihttprequest and set its delegate to its own progress bar.ASIHttpRequest and network queues handle the progress themselves.you need not to worry for that.I have implemented the same thing but at the moment I do not have the code to share with you.

Comment: i am doing same  but when user scroll table it crash on progress view i think its progress view get reinitialized and create problem

Comment: yes it might be, you should stop your table scrolling while the download functionality is going in progress.

Comment: but if i have 50 images in table at a time user can view 5 images status but when 5 images done i need to scroll table to show him status in that case again my application is crashing.

Comment: if i do not scroll everything works fine

Comment: you need to post some code that might be responsible for crash